# How to use a file from server using localhost?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a solution that grabs two files and compares them to see if they are the same or not. The `sourceFilePath` and `destFilePath` are both on my computer, but I want to be able to use the same solution to get files if they are on a different server. I will be able to test them by setting the parameters for the `sourceServer` and `_destServerList` to localhost. How can I make the solution use the file from the relative source server?

edit: I am using localhost for testing purposes before the solution is deployed.

This my current solution:

```
public class blarto
{
    private Server homeServer;
    private string homePath;
    private ServerList awayServers;
    private string awayPath;

    private bool ExecuteCommand()
    {
        if (File.Exists(awayPath))
        {
            GetSum(homePath);

            GetSum2(awayPath);

            if (GetSum != GetSum2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("they are different.");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
             Console.WriteLine("they are the same.");
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The destination file does not exist.");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have access to the servers, you could use a UNC path. Something like:

```
\\your-server-name\share\path\to\file.txt
```

or

```
\\your-server-name.domain.com\c$\path\to\file.txt
```

Otherwise, your web server is going to have to serve up the files. You'd have to build a small single-page web application or HTTP handler that takes a relative path, goes and looks at the appropriate place on the file system it's running on, load the file as a `Stream` or  `byte` array and write it out to the response stream (with appropriate content type and length headers). IIS will need to be able to handle the MIME type of the document.

The client will have to hold onto it in memory or write it to somewhere temporarily, which may force you to rethink your CRC implementation. All of this is amazingly insecure (you could theoretically give everyone access to every file on that server).

Alternatively, you could make the root folder of the files you need to compare a virtual directory, and then allow that directory to be browsed (an IIS setting). Then something like `http://localhost/root/path/to/file.txt` might work, but again, not secure at all.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like the file is on your localhost for testing, but will be on the server once you deploy.

If that is the case, start with the relative url of the file: `_srcFile = /uploads/testfile.txt;`

From that, get the real location using [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632.aspx):

```
var testFile = Server.MapPath(_srcFile);
```

Note: **MapPath** is also defined in [HttpServerUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx).